# Why are my chiles going slightly yellow and the flowers dropping?

Tags: diagnosis, chili

My chiles going slightly yellow. They only produced one fruit, which I took off when ripe. It is still flowering, but the flowers are dropping and not producing any more fruit!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmXOG.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

If I had to venture a guess, you've got a pollination problem due to lack of air flow and pollinators. That would lead it to produce flowers that drop off. Increasing air flow is as easy as adding a fan to run a few times a day. Adding pollinators might not be reasonable since it looks to be an indoor plant. My old fall-back is to hand pollinate with a small watercolor brush. Just brush each flower every couple of days, spreading the love. It'll do wonders.

The yellowing could be a number of things that I'm not qualified to diagnose.

Comment: thanks ive put a fan in its not lost any more flowers i think it might of been too much nitrogen in my feed causing the yellowing pf the leaves hopefully fruits again and hopefully not produce only one chilli hopefully get loads

Comment: if at some point you think this is solved, please mark the correct answer with the green check mark.